# Normalization of an addition of two values

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation, means

I have the following expression which I want to normalize:

```
val = v1+ v2
v1: has real values >0
v2: has values between 0 and 1
```

I want to normalize `val` such that it gives values between 0 and 1.

Best regards,

Comment: What are v1 and v2, random variables ?

Comment: @callculus they are real numbers

Comment: It quite depends on what you want to preserve. Per se, you could pick $\frac2\pi\arctan val$, or $\frac{val}{1+val}$.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with random variables ? I don´t get your problem.

Comment: My problem does not have anything to do with random variables, I just want to have an approach that could normalize val by returning values between 0 and 1. I think that what suggested @G. Sassatelli could solve the issue. I do not know if there are other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Given your definition:

```
val = v1+ v2
v1: has real values >0
v2: has values between 0 and 1
```

we know that `val` is a real value $>0$. Mapping this onto a value between $0$ and $1$ simply requires a monotonic function that stays small as its input goes to infinity. A simple option might be $\text{val}_{\text{norm}} = 1-2^{-\text{val}}$

If you wanted more weight on `v2` in the result you might consider normalizing  `v1` instead and then adding & scaling into the desired range.